# Voltage controlled current source using op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, current-source, 4-20ma

I have a sensor which gives a voltage output between 0V and 5V. I need to transform this sensor output to a current suited for a 4..20mA current loop.

The thing is, the current loop doesn't have a fixed resistance, so my current circuit does not seem to work, because as soon as you change the `RLOAD` (pot in the schematic for simpification) the output current does not stay within the range.

What do I need to change to make this circuit funtion as a variable 'constant current source' (not sure how to call it, I want constant current based on the input voltage but the input will be changin).

I'd really appreciate some guidance to figure out what I'm missing!

[image: schematic]

Comment: Where does this schematic come from? Is it your design?

Comment: @Stefan It's an adaptation from something I found online. I've been mucking around with the values in a simulator to try and figure out how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Can you provide the link for that circuit? Is there an explanation for the circuit online?

Comment: Look up a Howland current pump (simpler than what you have there). Alternatively, think about using an opamp to servo the voltage across a resistor in the emitter or source of a BJT or FET, with the outptu current at the collector/drain.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/332070/38098) question of mine. The first circuit would achieve probably more than you need (it's a two-quadrant design and you appear to need only one quadrant.) But what you are looking for is a wide compliance voltage range, I suspect. Anyway, give it a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched to a different solution, which has been tested both in simulation and in the real world.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTBUWs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I chose the [AD797](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD797.pdf) as the op-amp simply because I had them laying around, so that part isn't necessarily part of the final implementation. It also appears to be able to drive quite a resistive load with a maximum output voltage of `13V` and a maximum output current of `50mA`.

`RV` is the variable load (resistance of the cables, of the current sensor, etc...) and could be anywhere between 100Ω and 400Ω (I used a potentiometer in the circuit for simulation purposes)

`R1` has been chosen to be 250Ω (precision resistor) since `V = IR` or `I = V/R`, which owuld give us `I = 20mA` for the 5V input, or `I = 4mA` for a 1V input.

Should the load's resistance (`RV`) increase dramatically I'll have to look for another op-amp or a different solution alltogether but for now this will do!